# API Call from Custom field not showing the same data type

Tags: acumatica

Tried to do an API Call from a custom field that I published in one of our instance. The result value of the corresponding field didn't match the data type in our Data class. My field data type is *Int* but through the API, I got *String* instead. Also the field control element for this field is ComboBox

What I expect for the **Kundengruppe** value:

```
{
        "id": "4b2758c6-8d86-4357-871e-70621d09719d",
        "rowNumber": 3,
        "note": null,
        "Kundengruppe": {
            "value": "1" //
        },
        "UUID": {},
        "custom": {}
}
```

What I get:

```
{
        "id": "4b2758c6-8d86-4357-871e-70621d09719d",
        "rowNumber": 3,
        "note": null,
        "Kundengruppe": {
            "value": "bis 25.000,-  0,00%" //
        },
        "UUID": {},
        "custom": {}
}
```

ASPX & Data class attribute for custom field Kundengruppe

```
<px:PXDropDown runat="server" ID="CstPXDropDown40" DataField="UsrKundengruppe" CommitChanges="True" Enabled="True" SelectMethod="" />

------

[PXDBInt]
[PXIntList(new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, new string[] {"bis 25.000,-  0,00%", "25.001,- bis 50.000,- 3,75%", "50.001,- bis 100.000,- 7,50%", "100.001,- bis 200.000,-  10,00%", "200.001,- bis 300.000,- 12,00%", "300.001,- bis 500.000,- 14,50%", "500.001,- bis 750.000,-  16,50%", "750.001,- bis 1.000.000,- 18,50%", "ab 1.000.000,- 20,00%"})]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Kundengruppe Jahresumsatz von - bis Rabatt")]
```

Screenshots of some screens
[Dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUDfD.png), [Element properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts5z0.png)

Is there anyway to fixing this? I am not really familiar with C# in general. I also made a new fresh Endpoint to specifically for this custom field.

Note: I am using german localized version of Acumatica called Haufe x360

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data type on the web service endpoint screen, it defaults to string regardless of the column type:

[image]

Comment: I also already did that, the result said the Input state was not in correct format. 
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Input string was not in a correct format.",
    "exceptionType": "System.FormatException",
     ....
}

Comment: I think the fact that you have a PXIntList means that the API is forcing use of the Label instead of the Value. You might need to make another field that selects from the same field in the DB but without the Drop down so you can return the int value

Comment: Thank you, will try the solution you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the backend SQL Server tables for a stock PXDropDown (i.e. Shipping Rule property in Sales Order). If you set the Shipping Rule to "Ship Complete", then this sets "Ship Complete" in the database table as well. However, if you use a PXSelector, then the value is stored by reference in the database.

I don't think you are going to be able to do what you want to do with a PXDropDown. The framework doesn't have a way to go from the stored text database value back to the index value, and the REST API is just looking at what's in the database for the most part.

I would say change it to a PXSelector. Or you could write a graph extension that grabs the attribute values for the PXDropdown and saves the reference value to the database instead of the text value/saves it to another custom field (although you would have to make sure that the referential integrity will hold....for example if you add another dropdown value and that becomes value #1, then you've broken your referential integrity to the previous #1 value). The bottom line is that this can be done with a graph extension and a little bit of planning, but that will require C# code.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining so thoroughly. I really appreciate it. I will try to use PXSelector for the custom field